# How are .NET object Pen objects disposed if you don't explicitly call Dispose on them?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

While writing a small paint-like application (for myself), I originally had the following code being called in the onClick handler:

```
g.DrawEllipse((new Pen(pencolour, penSize)), e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
```

which I later changed to

```
Pen pen1 = new Pen(pencolour, penSize);
g.DrawEllipse(pen1, e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
pen1.Dispose();
```

My question is: are the two pieces of code equivalent, or does the first one create Pen objects which are never disposed of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are disposed when the Garbage Collector runs and determines the object is no longer in use. It is better to dispose of objects yourself, so the resources are freed immediately.

Also consider the use of the `using` statement:

```
using (Pen pen1 = new Pen(pencolour, penSize))
{
    g.DrawEllipse(pen1, e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
}
```

This automatically disposes the Pen, even if `DrawEllipse` would throw an exception, and the IDE will enforce that `pen1` is only available from within the using block.

Comment: +1 Minor nitpick- the GC does not call Dispose, it calls the finalizer (which if Pen is implemented properly should have the same effect, assuming that Dispose was never called by user code).

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks also for the pointer to the 'using' statement.

Answer (score 4):

As `Pen` implements `IDisposable`, it's better to use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure `Dispose` is called.

```
using (Pen pen1 = new Pen(pencolour, penSize))
{
    g.DrawEllipse(pen1, e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
}
```

If you don't, `pen1` will be GC-ed later as it's not used after it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The first creates Pen objects that are never disposed of.  They will eventually be GC'd, but they will temporarily leak whatever unmanaged resources a Pen wraps.

Comment: They don't leak exactly, they're just not disposed of until later.

Comment: Thus the use of the word 'temporarily' :-)  I consider it a leak when *at any time in your program's execution* unused resources are not cleaned up *and* not reachable for manual cleanup, which is the case here.  The fact that the garbage collector will eventually go and clean up the Pens is irrelevant- it's still *temporarily* leaking handles.

Answer (score 0):

The dispose surely is not called by the DrawEllipse method so the two snippets are not the same.